# How to tell Paris/ORM which table to use for the Model?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, idiorm

I've just added some Joins to my application which uses Idiorm/Paris, I'm finding that when I search via Model::factory() the object returned is getting the ID from the joined object, not the 'parent' object.

How can I tell Paris which table alias should form the model?

I'm doing this in a search context, so I don't think that I can use has_many() but I'd be happy to be wrong!

Sample code:

```
// Find a booking with a join
$query = Model::factory('Booking');
$query->where('booking.id', '2282');
$query->join(
    'customer',
    array('booking.id', '=', 'customer.booking_id'),
    'customer'
);
$bookingWithJoin = $query->find_one();

// Find the same booking, without a join
$query = Model::factory('Booking');
$query->where('id', '2282');
$bookingWithoutJoin = $query->find_one();

// The booking with a join gets the ID of the customer it's joined with
echo $bookingWithJoin->id .' != '. $bookingWithoutJoin->id;
```

Comment: public static $_table = 'my_user_table'; document here: http://paris.readthedocs.org/en/latest/models.html#model-classes

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the answer was `$query->select('booking.*');`

Does the equivelant of

`SELECT booking.* FROM bookings JOIN customer on booking.customer_id = customer.id`

So the returned results won't have `customer.*` fields included.